# use of age() function postgres

Tags: postgresql, functions, date, timestamp

I am trying to calculate the time since an event took place. The event timestamp will itself be the result of a MIN aggregate function. Is there a way to do this.

I have run a query to get the earliest date in my table which

```
SELECT MIN(date_column) FROM table
```

I also know that

```
AGE(timestamp '2015-10-5')
```

will give me the time elapsed since 5th Oct 2015. Is there a way to pass the result of the MIN query to the age function to find the length of time since that event?

Comment: you mean like `AGE(MIN(date_column))` ?

Comment: That's the idea but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Please show us a complete example, with `create table` statement, `insert`s to populate it with data, a complete query and the expected results, along with the results (and error(s), if any) you're currently getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `AGE`from you `MIN` date

> ```
> CREATE tABLE "table1" (date_column timestamp)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO "table1" VALUES ( NOW())
> ```

> ```
> SELECT AGE(MIN(date_column)) FROM "table1"
> ```

> ```
> | age              |
> | :--------------- |
> | -12:07:06.199423 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5dfd180f14836b68a3db2930aba74c6c)*

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with some help from nbk. Many thanks

```
CREATE TABLE temp (elapsed_time DATE);

INSERT INTO temp(elapsed_time)
SELECT MIN(current_table) FROM current_table;

SELECT AGE(MIN(elapsed_time)) FROM temp
```

Comment: That's a horrible way to solve this problem (and besides `select min(current_table)` makes no sense.

Comment: Yes. That should say something like ```SELECT MIN(current_table_column) FROM current_table``` I agree, it's not very elegant. I'd be interested if there is a less clumsy way of doing it.

Comment: See nbk's answer for a less clumsy way

Comment: I think I must have explained myself poorly. That doesn't give me what I need. I am in a current table and I find the oldest date in that table. I then want to find how long ago that was.

Comment: nbk's answer returns the age of the oldest value in that column. According to your problem description this is exactly what you want. That answer is identical to your hack with an intermediate table. See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bcf0a530b7ea8e2c87346ebea31dd67b

Comment: AHH. Right with  you now. I won't give up the day job just yet. Thanks